# How to activate and deactivate css classes of an element while hovering over a different element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay. So what I'm trying to create is https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QeWp.png

Each of the OL items has a description that matches it. The position of the descriptions is fixed.

What I'm trying to achieve is that when I hover the mouse over list item 1, it should display the description related to item 1. 
When I hover over item 2, the description of item 1 is replaced with the description of item 2.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="home-disciplines" >

<article class="home-disciplines__text home-disciplines__text_name_frontdesk home-copy hidden-phone home-disciplines__text_active"> 
    <h2 class="home-copy__title">Front Desk Use</h2>
    <p class="home-copy__txt">Guest facing users can&nbsp;easily check and monitor updates on room status or guest requests. What is more, phone call usage is optimised since everything gets done within the helius app. </p>
</article>

<article class="home-disciplines__text home-disciplines__text_name_repo home-copy hidden-phone"> 
    <h2 class="home-copy__title">Information Repository For Equipment</h2>
    <p class="home-copy__txt">Equipment related information available one click away (Warranty, vendor, repairment). From basic tracking all the way to future maintenance operations </p>
</article>

<article class="home-disciplines__text home-disciplines__text_name_worksheets home-copy hidden-phone"> 
    <h2 class="home-copy__title">Worksheets</h2>
    <p class="home-copy__txt"> Staff members fill out their worksheets as they conduct routine jobs. It's worth mentioning that as soon as an unwanted answer is marked, an issue report is auto created.</p>
</article>

<section class="home-disciplines__menu">

    <h3 class="home-disciplines__title j-fadeslidein-trigger j-visible" data-start-pos="3">Features</h3>
    <ol class="home-disciplines__list">

        <li class="home-disciplines__list-itm j-fadeslidein-trigger j-visible home-disciplines__list-itm_active" data-start-pos="3" data-target="frontdesk">  Front Desk Use </li>

        <li class="home-disciplines__list-itm j-fadeslidein-trigger j-visible" data-start-pos="3" data-target="repo">  Information Repository for Equipment </li>

        <li class="home-disciplines__list-itm j-fadeslidein-trigger j-visible" data-start-pos="3" data-target="worksheets">  Worksheets </li>

        <li class="home-disciplines__list-itm j-fadeslidein-trigger j-visible" data-start-pos="3" data-target="assignment">  Job Assignment </li>
```

I've set up a new css properties for 2 classes home-disciplines__text_active and home-discplines__list-itm_active which have an opacity of 1 and a higher z-index.

I'm using toggleclass method

```
$('.home-disciplines__list-itm').hover(
   function(){ $(this).toggleClass('home-disciplines__list-itm_active'); }
```

);

Firstly. this creates artifacts on the screen where the item 1 will be displayed along with item 2 unless I hover over the item 1 menu item again.

Secondly, how do I achieve something which sees which menu item i'm hovering over and switches to the relevant article? As in what type of a selector do I use? I don't see home-disciplines__list-itm working out here.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Haider_alee/tp9cv8m4/

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly. this creates artifacts on the screen where the item 1 will be displayed along with item 2 unless I hover over the item 1 menu item again.

This is the behavior of the `hover()` method. You should use `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` methods instead to get your expected behavior.

https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/
https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

> Secondly, how do I achieve something which sees which menu item i'm hovering over and switches to the relevant article? As in what type of a selector do I use? I don't see home-disciplines__list-itm working out here.

if you want to be more explicit, you can use the `each()` method:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

```
$('.home-disciplines__list-itm').each(function(){
    var item = $(this);

    item.mouseenter(function(){
       item.toggleClass('home-disciplines__list-itm_active');
    });

    item.mouseleave(function(){
       item.toggleClass('home-disciplines__list-itm_active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".home-disciplines__list-itm").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("home-disciplines__list-itm_active");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("home-disciplines__list-itm_active");
  }
);
```

By using the data attribute of "target" from which you will get to know which element you want.
For ex:

```
$('.home-disciplines__list-itm').hover(function(){
    alert( $(this).data('target') );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve what you want is have a HTML like this:

```
    <div class="mydiv">
        <p>some thext here....</p>
        <a href="" class="showOnParentHover">more...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="mydiv">
        <p>some thext here....</p>
        <a href="" class="showOnParentHover">more...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="mydiv">
        <p>some thext here....</p>
        <a href="" class="showOnParentHover">more...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="mydiv">
        <p>some thext here....</p>
        <a href="" class="showOnParentHover">more...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="mydiv">
        <p>some thext here....</p>
        <a href="" class="showOnParentHover">more...</a>
    </div>
```

and CSS like this:

```
    .mydiv .showOnParentHover{
        display: none;
    }
    .mydiv:hover .showOnParentHover{
        display: block;
    }
```

In this example, when `.mydiv` is hovered, its `.showOnParentHover` child will be visible, otherwise it's hidden;